# Can I bring keto powder through airport security?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airports, airport-security, food-and-drink

I've started doing keto  (more specifically a power keto where you put it in water).. anyways can my powder keto pass security and a bigish plastic bottle (with a metal ball to help shake it up)?

Comment: Which country are you traveling from?

Comment: And which country travelling to?

Answer (score 5):

The answer may depend on which airport(s) you’re travelling through and/or the size of the containers. The [TSA website](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/all) says:

> Powder-like substances greater than 12 oz. / 350 mL must be placed in a separate bin for X-ray screening. They may require additional screening and containers may need to be opened. For your convenience, we encourage you to place non-essential powders greater than 12 oz. in checked bags.